# CSS transition stutters after being applied to element with CSS animation

Tags: css, angularjs, transform, transition

I'm building an AngularJS application that shows and hides an element by transitioning its opacity. The element is also being rotated by applying a CSS keyframe animation. The problem I'm having is the transition or animation stutters.

When the element has an opacity of 1 and the transition fades it out to 0 then the element appears to go back a few frames. This is better demonstrated in a GIF. You can see it jump back just before the opacity changes.

[image]

This is my CSS.

```
.square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 50px;
  background: black;
}

.appear.ng-hide-add {
   -webkit-transition: opacity 300ms linear;
  opacity: 1;
}

.appear.ng-hide-add.ng-hide-add-active {
  opacity: 0;
}

.appear.ng-hide-remove {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 300ms linear;
  opacity: 0;
}

.appear.ng-hide-remove.ng-hide-remove-active {
  opacity: 1;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.rotate {
  -webkit-animation: rotate 1.5s infinite linear;  
}
```

This is my HTML.

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-init="show = true">
  <p>Toggle the opacity of the square. Sometimes the rotation is interrupted when the opacity transitions from 1 to 0.</p>
  <button ng-click="show =!show">Toggle</button>
  <div class="square appear rotate" ng-show="show"></div>
</div>
```

You can play with the whole thing in this [codepen](http://codepen.io/tatey/pen/DfGpw). Hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: I tried (I'm sure you did too) wrapping the square in another element and hiding/showing the wrapper, but it doesn't seem to help: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/DctGj

Comment: Yes, that didn't work for me either. Ended up going with your answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/24474564/106997

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one more workaround just for the fun of it. Slightly less ugly than the first one I suggested. Change the box background color opacity: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/DpuEh

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-init="show = true">
  <button ng-click="show = !show">Toggle</button>
  <div class="square appear rotate" ng-class="{'hidden': !show}"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 50px;
   -webkit-transition: background 300ms linear;
  background: black;
}

.square.hidden {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

I'm using `rgba` to set the background opacity. Just setting the background to `white` would also have worked in this simple case.

Comment: Thanks Henrik. Changing this to the accepted answer for the question as it is a 100% CSS solution. If you can leverage jQuery you may want to consider wrapping `.animate`. It's smoother the first time and completely smooth thereafter. See https://gist.github.com/tatey/3f1933d2d6d8b4dbe801

Answer (score 1):

This is evidently a WebKit bug. This is clearly not how the CSS should behave, and it does behave as expected in Firefox if you remove the vendor prefixes. You will notice that the animation resets when an additional animations/transitions are applied. This is similar to a known bug that was recently fixed in which multiple CSS transitions being applied at different times would cause a layout flash. I would recommend reporting the bug to the WebKit team so that it can be fixed.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question.

Comment: @ccjmne It's not a fix no, but I am trying to point him in the right direction, as he asked for. It's clearly a browser bug and should be reported to the WebKit team.

Comment: I'm not critiquing his question or asking for clarification, I'm telling him he's not doing anything wrong and that it's clearly a bug, similar to past known bugs, that should be reported. I've clarified my answer in case that wasn't clear.

Comment: I'll raise a bug with the webkit project and link back to it from here. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Ugly workaround that may or may not be suitable, depending on your situation: instead of hiding the element ([shows the bug](http://codepen.io/tatey/pen/DfGpw)) or a container ([also shows the bug](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/DctGj)), you can fade in a background-colored element on top of it.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-init="show = false">
  <button ng-click="show =!show">Toggle</button>
  <div class="appear" ng-show="show"></div>
  <div class="square rotate"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.appear {
  background: white;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

Obviously you might need more sophisticated CSS for a more sophisticated layout, but hopefully you get the idea.

CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/IwBHj

Comment: Ugly, but genius. Fortunately it's contained within one template at the moment. I'd consider wrapping this in a directive if I needed to reuse it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using translate3D on the transform to force hardware acceleration.

```
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
```

This uses hardware acceleration (GPU) for the CSS transitions.